# Copy or create dom element on click and be able to drag

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-sortable

This is something tricky that I can't wrap my head around a feasible solution. I have a list of elements, in this case, recipes. These recipes use jquery's sortable feature. What I want to do is have a user be able to grab a recipe from the list and drag and drop it into another div that is also sortable. I want to have a copy feature because the user may use that recipe multiple times.

So what I'm thinking is when a user clicks, I need to create a new dom element, that way I can maintain the original recipe list. But I have no idea how I can copy the item and have it still be draggable at the same time. That's at least how I've thought of it - any other ideas would be great.

My only workaround was clicking a recipe and clone that recipe dropping it in another div. then you can drag that element wherever. But that's not an acceptable ux in my mind.

any ideas??

Comment: My appropriately asked at http://ux.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Take a look at [this jQuery UI example](http://jqueryui.com/draggable/#sortable). It clones the element and also implements sorting. Probably not exactly what you're looking for but it might give you some ideas.